# Chrome extension enable content script to access iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Question is simple: Is there any way to enable a content script (through `executeScript()`) to be able to access an iframe on the current webpage (say `stackoverflow.com`) that has the same origin of the extension itself?

To put to rest: I realize you can communicate through postMessage, hashing, and so forth from the iframe script to its parent script, but my main goal is to add events onto the iframe directly from a content script rather than having to pass a message (and create a middle man).

I believe injected content scripts run on the page "in their own little world", in which the page itself, nor other content scripts can access, so it leads me to believe Chrome could possibly `allow` these scripts access to iframes of its own origin (the extension url itself).

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, the iframe would have a url of the chrome extension itself, under the protocol `chrome-extension://`. The parent page of the iframe could have any url, say `http://stackoverflow.com` for instance. So trying to access the iframe from a content script generally wont pass the `same-origin-policy`...The question is if there is a way around this using Chrome's Extension library.

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to figure out the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly run a content-script on a page and interact with any embedded iframes. I was working on a project recently where I needed to do this.

I don't have a solution in pure javascript so this would require you to include the jQuery.js library, if that works for you.

In the content-script running on the parent page I did the following:

```
//CAPTURE FRAME LOAD
$("#frameID").load(function () {

    //Create an object for the frame
    var firstFrame = window.parent.frames[0].document;

    //Set JQuery events to run in the context of the frame
    $("#buttonID", firstFrame).click(function(){

        //Capture click event of a button within the frame

    });


});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This I'm sure would work under the same domain, but when my iframe has a `chrome-extension` protocol, and the page is some foreign webpage (under `http://`) this wont pass the same origin policy...updating question to clarify

Comment: If this DID work for you, was there maybe some other things you did (possibly in the manifest file) that enabled it to work under different domains?

Comment: In my case the parent page (which is where my content-script is pegged to) and the iframe are running within the same domain. I would imagine if this is not the case, it will simply be a case of declaring the iframe domain in your manifest permissions.

Comment: right, I'm figuring its something like that...in my case the iframe literally comes from my extension, its `src` is generated from `chrome.extension.getURL()`

Comment: @QF_Developer can you please have a look at my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288202/inject-javascript-in-an-iframe-using-chrome-extension seems like I want exactly the same as him