# Inject javascript in an iframe using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

There are lots of questions/answers on injecting javascript into the document page. What I really want to do is inject javascript in an iframe within the document.

To be clear, that iframe doesn't belong to the same domain as the document. I've already tried it through console (not through extension) but was unable to do so.

I'm very curious if this is something that can be done using a chrome-extension ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes, you can use [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#frames) property in manifest.json like this:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["content_frame.js"],
    "all_frames": true
}],
```

By setting `all_frames` to `true` you will inject/include `content_frame.js` javascript file into top document and all iframes. In case you just need javascript injected in iframe but not in top document you can check inside your `content_frame.js` file like this:

```
if (parent === top) {
    // here you can put your code that will run only inside iframe
}
```

Comment: I'm just a beginner, I've coded only one extension till date. Do you have any complete example or any link I can go through.

Comment: @coding_idiot I expanded my answer a bit more and added link to documentation on how to use content_scripts. I hope it's more clear now?

Comment: You can use `include_globs` and `exclude_globs` to target specific frames instead of doing an if statement in your script: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#include_globs

Comment: This unfortunately does not work on iframes with empty src="" - programatically created and populated documents.

Comment: I think the logic to check whether in an iframe or not is not `parent === top` but rather `self !== top`.