# How to access iframe in popup.html in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

I have a chrome extension that opens a webpage via an iframe inside it's popup.html

What I need to do is detect when the user browses to certain URLs in the iframe, and then open those URLs as a new tab.

I was trying to access the .location of the iframe, but unfortunately was getting the policy issues between "chrome-extensions" and "http"

I've been researching, and I'm seeing a lot of notes on using content scripts, but I'm really not understanding how they work fully. Most examples are trying to inject code into current pages in the browser itself so I don't think they apply. Is a content script what I need?

Any help would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible as chrome-extension popup is different domain site you cannot access it within your site.

Comment: So it's not possible to inject code even with a content script into an iframe that's inside of popup.html?

Comment: I am afraid its not possible.

Comment: Well that would be why it wasn't working, haha. Thanks for the help, saved me a ton of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do the same thing and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19288288/2996624) answer on SO. This worked for me and may be can work in our case as well. Just in case if the link may stop working in future, i'm copying his answer here:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["content_frame.js"],
    "all_frames": true
}],
```

By setting `all_frames` to `true` you will inject/include `content_frame.js` javascript file into top document and all iframes. In case you just need javascript injected in iframe but not in top document you can check inside your `content_frame.js` file like this:

```
if (parent === top) {
    // here you can put your code that will run only inside iframe
}
```