# Is there a way in javascript to get all iframes that don't violate same-origin-policy with getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension that needs to get an html5 video element on a page, but some video elements were in iframes. I added onto my function to search through iframes, but I started getting errors because of the Same-Origin-Policy related to iframes with different src domains.

In my function, is there an easy way to exclude iframes that violate the Same-Origin-Policy? Or better yet (even though likely not possible), is there a way to still search iframes with different src domains from the main page?

The function in question:

```
function getVideo() {
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    if (videos.length >= 1) {
        return videos[0];
    }
    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    if (iframes.length >= 1) {
        for (const frame of iframes) {
            videos = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("video");
            if (videos.length >= 1) {
                return videos[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // if a video doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit:

See bottom of answer for current solution.

---

#### Original Answer:

Just when you think you have searched long enough on here to warrant a question, you find something that is actually useful.

Based off the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288202/inject-javascript-in-an-iframe-using-chrome-extension), I updated my code to this:

```
function getVideo() {
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    if (videos.length >= 1) {
        return [videos[0], "main"];
    }

    // Code that will run only inside iframe
    if (parent === top) {
        var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
        if (videos.length >= 1) {
            return [videos[0], "iframe"];
        }
    }
    return [null, null]; // if a video doesn't exist
}
```

And included this in my manifest, so that the script would be injected into the iframes as well:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "all_frames": true,
    ...
    
    ...
}],
```

This works, but it does make my other functions pretty ugly. Example:

```
// if a video exists, set it to the speed and give a notification
function setSpeed(newSpeed) {
    var returnVal = getVideo();
    var video = returnVal[0], type = returnVal[1];
    if (video != null && type === "main") {
        video.playbackRate = newSpeed;
        inWindowAlert("Speed: " + newSpeed, 1000);
        setIcon(newSpeed);
    }
    if (parent === top) {
        if (video != null && type === "iframe") {
            video.playbackRate = newSpeed;
            inWindowAlert("Speed: " + newSpeed, 1000);
            setIcon(newSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

I will try to come up with a cleaner solution, but for now it works. Hope this helps anyone.

---

#### New Solution:

Just wanted to update this to say that I completely rewrote the extension's logic to handle this more easily.

The new solution lets each instance of the content script running in each frame run independently and simply collect all videos in its context. I also collect them in a `Set` to avoid accidental duplication.

I still want to go through again to eliminate the usage of global variables, but the extension works well enough now, so it will likely remain as it is for awhile.

New code:

```js
function getVideos() {
  let new_videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
  if (new_videos.length >= 1) {
    VIDEOS = new Set(new_videos);
    return VIDEOS;
  }
  return new Set();
}
```

and

```js
// set video to the speed and give a notification, restricts available speeds
function setSpeed(newSpeed, video) {
  //* BUG-FIX: playback rates below 0.07 rather than 0 were causing errors
  newSpeed = newSpeed > 16 ? 16 : newSpeed < 0.07 ? 0 : newSpeed;
  // limit decimal values to 2 digits, + in front truncates 2.00 -> 2
  SPEED = +newSpeed.toFixed(2);
  video.playbackRate = SPEED;
  tempAlert("Speed: " + SPEED, 2000, video);
  setIcon(SPEED);
}
```

Where `VIDEOS` and `SPEED` are global variables.

Comment: If you set all_frames to false in the Manifest.json - then I don't think you need to check that the fame parent === top.  The frame you get is always the top frame (and not all the subframes that could exist in a webpage).

Comment: If I set `all_frames` to `false`, how would I get video elements from within iframes on the page? The majority of the videos the extension acts on are in iframes because websites often embed videos from other sites. 

_\*Note: I did completely rewrite the functions to work differently, but I am curious if you had a different solution._